# Need help understanding portion of script (globs and references)

Tags: perl

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250505/capture-variable-assignments-in-a-perl-eval), esp the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8251118/2534803) from Mr Eric Strom, and had a question regarding a portion of the more "magical" element within. Please review the linked question for the context as I'm only trying to understand the inner portion of this block:

```
for (qw($SCALAR @ARRAY %HASH)) {
    my ($sigil, $type) = /(.)(.+)/;
    if (my $ref = *$glob{$type}) {
        $vars{$sigil.$name} = /\$/ ? $$ref : $ref
    }
}
```

So, it loops over three words, breaking each into two vars, `$sigil` and `$type`.  The `if {}` block is what I am not understanding.  I suspect the portion inside the `( .. )` is getting a symbolic reference to the content within `$glob{$type}`... there must be some "magic" (some esoteric element of the underlying mechanism that I don't yet understand) relied upon there to determine the type of the "pointed-to" data?

The next line is also partly baffling.  Appears to me that we are assigning to the vars hash, but what is the rhs doing?  We did not assign to `$_` in the last operation (`$ref` was assigned), so what is being compared to in the `/\$/` block?  My guess is that, if we are dealing with a scalar (though I fail to discern how we are), we deref the `$ref` var and store it directly in the hash, otherwise, we store the reference.

So, just looking for a little tale of what is going on in these three lines.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements of the iteration are *strings*. Since we don't have a lexical variable at the top of the loop, the element variable is `$_`. And it retains that value throughout the loop. Only one of those strings has a literal dollar sign, so we're telling the difference between `'$SCALAR'` and the other cases.

So what it is doing is getting 3 slots out of a package-level [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) (sometimes shortened, with a *little* ambiguity to "glob"). `*g{SCALAR}`, `*g{ARRAY}` and `*g{HASH}`. The glob stores a hash and an array as a reference, so we simply store the reference into the hash. But, the glob stores a scalar as a *reference* to a scalar, and so needs to be dereferenced, to be stored as just a scalar.

So if you had a glob `*a` and in your package you had:

```
our $a = 'boo';
our @a = ( 1, 2, 3 );
our %a = ( One => 1, Two => 2 );
```

The resulting hash would be:

```
{ '$a' => 'boo'
, '%a' => { One => 1, Two => 2 }
, '@a' => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
};
```

Meanwhile the glob can be thought to look like this:

```
a => 
    { SCALAR => \'boo'
    , ARRAY  => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    , HASH   => { One => 1, Two => 2 }
    , CODE   => undef
    , IO     => undef 
    , GLOB   => undef
    };
```

---

So to specifically answer your question.

```
if (my $ref = *$glob{$type}) {
    $vars{$sigil.$name} = /\$/ ? $$ref : $ref
}
```

If a slot is not used it is undef. Thus `$ref` is assigned either a reference or `undef`, which evaluates to `true` as a reference and `false` as `undef`. So *if* we have a reference, then store the value of that glob slot into the hash, taking the reference stored in the hash, if it is a "container type" but taking the value if it is a scalar. And it is stored with the key `$sigil . $name` in the `%vars` hash.

Comment: Oh... I get it.  Definite perl trickery going on but that's kinda neat!  One last bit of confusion... in the original linked answer, the variable `$glob` stores the value `*main::eval_code` (for example, copied from the output of a test script; note the leading `*`).  When `*$glob{SCALAR}` is evaluated, is it evaluating (in pseudo-code) `*(*main::eval_code){SCALAR}`?  How do the `*`'s get resolved?

Comment: The usual chastisement about using `$a` for your own purposes!

Comment: @Jon, You know the sigils `$`, `@`, and `%`, and perhaps you know the somewhat-legacy CODE sigil `&` as in `&call_this_sub( 'a' )`, well symbols have a sigil, too. The least-known, and that's `*`, which tells perl to address that to the system table. The "symbol" and the typeglob are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

You have hit upon one of the most arcane parts of the Perl language, and I can best explain by referring you to [Symbol Tables and Typeglobs](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001527/ch08.html) from [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy)'s excellent *Mastering Perl*. Note also that there are further references to the relevant sections of Perl's own documentation at the bottom of the page, the most relevant of which is [*Typeglobs and Filehandles*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) in `perldata`.

Essentially, the way perl symbol tables work is that every *package* has a *"stash"* -- a "symbol table hash" -- whose name is the same as the package but with a pair of trailing semicolons. So the stash for the default package `main` is called `%main::`. If you run this simple program

```
perl -E"say for keys %main::"
```

you will see all the familiar built-in identifiers.

The *values* for the stash elements are references to *typeglobs*, which again are hashes but have keys that correspond to the different data types, `SCALAR`, `ARRAY`, `HASH`, `CODE` etc. and values that are references to the data item with that type and identifier.

Suppose you define a scalar variable `$xx`, or more fully, `$main:xx`

```
our $xx = 99;
```

Now the *stash* for the `main` package is `%main::`, and the typeglob for all data items with the identifier `xx` is referenced by `$main::{xx}` so, because the *sigil* for typeglobs is a star `*` in the same way that scalar identifiers have a dollar `$`, we can dereference this as `*{$main::{xx}}`. To get the reference to the *scalar* variable that has the identifier `xx`, this typeglob can be indexed with the `SCALAR` string, giving `*{$main::{xx}}{SCALAR}`. Once more, this is a *reference* to the variable we're after, so to collect its value it needs dereferencing once again, and if you write

```
say ${*{$main::{xx}}{SCALAR}};
```

then you will see `99`.

That may look a little complex when written in a single statement, but it is fairly stratighforward when split up. The code in your question has the variable `$glob` set to a reference to a typeglob, which corresponds to this with respect to `$main::xx`

```
my $type = 'SCALAR';
my $glob = $main::{xx};
my $ref  = *$glob{$type};
```

now if we `say $ref` we get `SCALAR(0x1d12d94)` or similar, which is a reference to `$main::xx` as before, and printing `$$ref` will show `99` as expected.

The subsequent assignment to `@vars` is straightforward Perl, and I don't think you should have any problem understanding that once you get the principle that a packages symbol table is a stash of typglobs, or really just a hash of hashes.

Comment: And... when I assign `$main::{name}` to something, I'm getting the "pointer" to the stash entry (for 'name'), which would be the glob slot for that symbol.  I was a bit puzzled as to why I had the leading `*` sigil until I printed out `$main::{name}` and `$main::name`.

Comment: Borodin, thank you for the quick lesson on perl's glob internals.  You are right, it's a very arcane area of the language, but clearly, quite useful at times.  I accepted the other chap's answer as the "answer to the question", but don't interpret that to mean I value your response any less!  I used both answers to gain the required understanding.  Thank you!